# ReactJS parse data fetch from API to another component

Tags: reactjs

I have data that getting from API in one component. For example, I have a file called **Inventory.js**

```
export function Inventory() {
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/products";
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/products")
      .then((response) => {
        setProduct(response.data);
      });
  }, [url]);
  console.log(product);
```

My variable `product` will now consist of all the data from API.

Now I have another file **ProductEditForm.js**

```
export const ProductEditForm = ({ onSubmit }) => {
    console.log(product) <-- Not working here?
}
```

How can I get product data from **Inventory.js** to **ProductEditForm.js**?

Comment: Is `ProductEditForm` child of `Inventory` component?

Comment: Yes, it's a child compoenent

Answer (score 0):

```
    make an API call in parent component and pass the data as props to both above component
    
    //demo
    
    //parent component
    
    export default function App(){
    const [data,setData]=React.useState();
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/products")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      });
  }, [url]);
     return(
    <div>
    <Inventory data={data}/>
    <ProductEditForm data={data}/>
    </div>
    )
    }

//inventory
export default function Inventory({data}){
return(
<div></div>)
}
```